# Creating a sample vector of variable length for metadata

Tags: r

I have a simple problem to address first
I have to create a vector for my stage then need to generate another vector for no of samples which differs in number.

The below code does that what i need but is there anyway to combine both of them together into one

```
stage <- c("Blast","HSC","LSC")
 sample1 <- c(rep("Blast", 2), rep("HSC",4), rep("LSC", 3))
 Sample1 <- ave(sample1, sample1, FUN = function(i) paste0(i, '_', seq_along(i)))
 Sample1
```

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using `paste` im `Map` is another way.

```
stage <- c(Blast = 2, HSC = 4, LSC = 3)
unlist(Map(function(x, y) paste(x, seq_len(y), sep="_"), names(stage), stage)
     , FALSE, FALSE)
#[1] "Blast_1" "Blast_2" "HSC_1"   "HSC_2"   "HSC_3"   "HSC_4"   "LSC_1"  
#[8] "LSC_2"   "LSC_3"
```

Comment: Wonderfullllllllll

Answer (score 2):

Or another approach...

```
stage <- c("Blast","HSC","LSC")
count <- c(2, 4, 3)

paste(rep(stage, count), sequence(count), sep = "_")

[1] "Blast_1" "Blast_2" "HSC_1"   "HSC_2"   "HSC_3"   "HSC_4"   "LSC_1"   "LSC_2"   "LSC_3"
```

Comment: thank you for another approach/way of addressing my problem